# Classifying the following set in the arithmetical hierarchy?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof, computability

Let $A:= \{\langle i,j\rangle \in \mathbb{N} \mid W_i \cap W_j = \emptyset\}$ where $W_i$ corresponds to the domain of the universal partial computable function $\varphi_i$.

Let us show that $A \in \Pi_2^0$.

$z=\langle i,j\rangle \in A \Leftrightarrow W_i \cap W_j = \emptyset \Leftrightarrow  \forall x \exists t \ (T[\pi_1(i),x,\pi_1(t)]   \rightarrow \neg T[\pi_2(j),x,\pi_2(t)]) \Leftrightarrow \forall x \exists t \ (\neg T[\pi_1(i),x,\pi_1(t)] \vee \neg T[\pi_2(j),x,\pi_2(t)])$

where the predicate : $\neg T[\pi_1(i),x,\pi_1(t)] \vee \neg T[\pi_2(j),x,\pi_2(t)] \in \Delta_0$ ($T$ stands for the Kleene's predicate). Hence $A \in \Pi_2^0$.

Let us show that $A$ is $\Pi_2^0$-complete. We will prove that $\text{Tot}\le_m A$ where $\text{Tot}:= \{e \in \mathbb{N} \mid W_e = \mathbb{N}\}$ (indeed $\text{Tot}$ is $\Pi_2^0$-complete).

Let $e \in \text{Tot}$ hence $W_e = \mathbb{N}$. Moreover, we can notice that if $j \in \mathbb{N}$ is the index of the nowhere defined function (which is computable) then $W_e \cap W_j= \emptyset$. Hence if we consider the pair $\langle e,j \rangle$ (that encoding is in fact primitive recursive), we get that $\langle e,j \rangle \in A$.

Hence $e \in \text{Tot} \Leftrightarrow \langle e,j \rangle \in A$ and then $\text{Tot}\le_m A$. We can conclude that $A$ is $\Pi_2^0$-complete.

I was wondering if the last point of the proof was correct and if I should write more carefully the total computable function used in the reduction step ?

Also, is there a more "algorithmic" way (with machines for example) to see the reduction step ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your completeness proof is not correct: $\langle e,j\rangle$ is in $A$ for **every** choice of $e$, not just those in $\mathrm{Tot}$. In fact, $A$ is merely $\Pi^0_1$ (but it is $\Pi^0_1$-complete).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Indeed thank you for the precision, you are right, it is just not specific to the indices of $\text{Tot}$ ! However with the definition given, I do not see why $A$ is in $\Pi_1^0$...

Comment: Think about the complement: what sort of evidence would convince you that $W_i\cap W_j\not=\emptyset$? It would be some triple $\langle x,s,t\rangle$ such that $x$ enters $W_i$ at stage $s$ and enters $W_j$ at stage $t$. This line of thought can turn into a proof that the complement of $A$ is $\Sigma^0_1$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Indeed I see now, using the complement it gives the existence of an $x$ in both $W_i$ and $W_j$ and finally it gives two existential quantifiers ! It makes the statement $\Sigma_1^0$ ! Now I guess that for the completeness, it is the standard method (or maybe using the Halting Set or its complement).